# Infinite scrolling using AJAX, Javascript/jQuery, the DOM and Facebook Like button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, facebook, dom

I am preparing to implement a Twitter-like infinite scrolling to my product pages. That is, loading additional page portions using AJAX when I am crossing certain scroll thresholds. But I am unsure how the topics in the title are affected after such loading. My questions are the following:

1. For each new batch of elements being loaded with AJAX, will the DOM be updated for these new elements OR totally renewed? What happens with the old DOM?
2. Will I be able to use Javascript and jQuery on these new DOM elements exactly like I have on the DOM I start off with for the page? I guess this relates to the first question.
3. For each load, I will load say 9 new products. Each product has a FB Like button which is utilising FB Open Graph API. Will the new products Like elements go through the same asynchronous modification which happens to the DOM elements I start off with so that a proper Like submission is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's begin one by one.

1. The DOM, in your intent, should only be updated, not renewed. There
   is no old DOM since what you do is to insert new elements on them.
2. Yes, you'll be able to do that. Be careful though with event
   listeners because if you start them wrong, you'll have to attach new
   event listener to those new nodes again. For example:

   $('body').on('click','a.addToCart',function(){}) // Will match present and future nodes
   $('a.addToCart').on('click',function(){}); // Will only match present nodes
3. Yes, you'll need to do the same process for each button again.

**Bonus tip**: If you care about mobile environments, you should keep your DOM as clean as you can by deleting nodes you won't need.

Answer (score 0):

1. Just use document.appendChild() for adding new Elements to the DOM. (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp)
   Rebuilding the hole page would be a waste of time ;)
2. There should be no problem. I've done it many times without any problems. If you are using jQuery Mobile you have to refresh the new elements maybe. (Look at the methods of die jQuery Mobile Widget you are using, if it needs refreshing)
3. I don't have much experience with the facebook api, but i would say "yes" =)

edit: I had a link to a german site in my answer. I've forgot that this is an english site ;)